# User data not updating in admin panel and forms django

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try to update user data (in admin panel or form) it does nothing and give 0 errors. In the admin panel, it says it updated, but data stays the same.

Here's my model.py: https://pastecode.io/s/jx4jpt0x

Comment: if any codes in admin.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.user_role = self.base_role
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You should not modify the `save` method since this is not required. You have already defined the `user_role` attribute with default value as `base_role`.

Comment: Can't believe I spend so much of trying just to remove 4 lines. I love programming ‍